# Script is written dynamically with variables inside SRC, but it does not executes as when it's written statically

Tags: javascript, callback, blogger

I've been trying to show a post list in Blogger that varies depending on the month/year. How this exhibition is dynamic, I need to pass these two values (month/year) to a variable inside `<script>` tag's `src` attribute – what I'm able to do –, but the script is not executed  (even being written inside the HTML). Below, I write how the code works and what I've done until now:

```html
<script>
function textospordata(json) {
 // Here the commands that write a list with specific texts go.
}
</script>

<!-- The static script (with fixed values) works. The callback textsbydate() is executed and the texts are listed. -->
<script src="http://mysite.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?published-min=2019-05-01T00:00:00&amp;published-max=2019-05-31T23:59:59&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=textsbydate"></script>

<!-- When it's written dynamically, the script is even created inside the page, but the callback isn't called and so the texts aren't listed. -->
<script>
const urlAno = '2019'; // Year example. The code to get it is another.
const urlMes = '05'; // Month example. The code to get it is another.
const srcUrl = 'http://mysite.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?published-min='+urlAno+'-'+urlMes+'-01T00:00:00&published-max='+urlAno+'-'+urlMes+'-31T23:59:59&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=textsbydate';

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = srcUrl;
document.getElementById('body-post').appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Besides what is inside the *snippet*, I've already tried to write the `<script>` tag using `document.write("<script src='"+srcUrl+"'></"+"script>");`. I've already also tried to insert the code inside a function and call it separately, and besides to try to use the `onload` and a `script.async: false`.

In every attempt, the `<script>` tag is written inside the HTML exactly how it should be written (`<script src="http://mysite.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?published-min=2019-05-01T00:00:00&amp;published-max=2019-05-31T23:59:59&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=textsbydate"></script>`, like in the example), but the texts are not listed and nothing works when compared to when it is written in the static way.

And at last, I believe the soluction be to do the dynamic script be executed synchronously. I think it must be executed before page's DOM. I've tried to read some answers to similar questions here at S.O., but without success. And in addition, the console does not show any error about it.

What may be wrong in my code?

Comment: Is it not possible to create the variables at the server, and include a regular script tag to the HTML before sending the markup to a client?

Comment: No, @Teemu. Unfortunately, in the Blogger, that's not possible. =\

Comment: The only thing that I see that could be wrong is the line const srcUrl = 'mysite.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?published-min='+urlAno+'-'+urlMes+'-01T00:00:00&published-max='+urlAno+'-'+urlMes+'-31T23:&...'; Have you tried as const srcUrl = ".../feeds/posts/default?published-min='+urlAno+'-'+urlMes+'-01T00:00:00&published-max='+urlAno+'-'+urlMes+'-31T23:59:59&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=textsbydate"; ? From my experience with Blogger sometimes the " and ' in the script lines do matter. removed parts of your line as it was too long but I hope you can see my point.

Comment: @OsvaldoCorreia, Got it. I tried to replace the first and the last ' with ", and it didn't work. However, I noticed that it looks like that it would work if I use "https" instead "http" in the URL. And now, console shows me a error that I'm trying to fix it. It tells me that "It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened." At least, I have a new way to go. I thank you for your support, man. God bless you!